# How to create a random pair in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi all I am trying to create a random pairs of the specific number of mines in my minessweeper game.

so I need to make method that takes a mines number, (width,hight) and returns a list of random positions [(x,y)]

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no prior attempt at a solution or specific, re-producible problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/randoms

This should help. Basically just use the `System.Random` module (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html)